# How to make a figure invisible the first time I open in in Matlab GUIDE

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, figure

I'm making a GUI using matlab GUIDE. Since GUIDE doesn't support tabs, I have a pop down menu where the user selects different options. Depending on the selected options, certain buttons appear and disappear, this is easily handled by turning the handle visibility on/off.

However, the first time I run the GUI, i can see all my buttons, even though their default handle visibility is off. The moment I select something from the pop down menu, everything is fine.

**How do I make a figure invisible for the very first time the GUI is opened?**

Thanks!

Comment: You should consider using GUI Layout Toolbox from the file exchange.  It provides tabs and a much more robust programming environment for sophisticated GUIs.  http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27758-gui-layout-toolbox

Answer (score 1):

Try the `drawnow` command at the end of the initialization code of your GUI (see doc [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html)). It should force the update of the GUI and hopefully set the visibility of your objects correctly.

Comment: Hmm..I thought it worked initially. But it doesn't seem to work always.

Comment: This is kind of a weird behaviour. If you want tabs in your gui, you should check the `uitab` object ([uitab](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/tab-panels-uitab-and-relatives/))